# DateTime.TryParseExact not working with expected string

Tags: c#, datetime

Hi I have the following method and I'm passing it the value "07 Jan 2014 13:48:46" and from what I understand the TryParseExact should be matching the format "dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss" and returning true, however it is returning false, any ideas?

```
string[] formats= {"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss",
                   "dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss",
                   "dd MMM yyyy",
                   "hh-mm-ss",
                   "dd-MM-yyyy",
                   "dd-MM-yy",
                  };

 DateTime result;
 if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value, formats, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
 {
     return result;
 }
 return null;
```

Comment: What is CurrentCulture?

Comment: CultureInfo.CurrentCulture is en-GB

Answer (score 15, accepted):

24-hour time requires use of `HH`, not `hh`.  Lowercase `h` is for 12 hour time.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @NickSpicer Also remember that the `:` chars inside `formats` represent [the time separator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.timeseparator.aspx) of the culture used. If your current culture uses a period, like `bn-IN` (Bangla (India)) does, it won't parse with a colon.

Answer (score 4):

Because none of your format have *24-hour clock*.

[`hh` specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#hhSpecifier) is for `01` to `12`. It doesn't have `13` as an hour.

Use [`HH` specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#HH_Specifier) instead which is for `00` to `23`.

For more information, take a look at;

- [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)